# MovieMasher utility script

Tags: javascript, php, xml, flash

I'm trying to generate video from a sequence of images using movie masher. While trying to upload images from user interface of movie masher; it shows "Problem loading utility script".

I didn't find from where to load utility script and where it is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use media upload function then first of all you have to create 'upload' and 'user' folder and please check media.xml file inside xml folder, there you will find all the media upload functions.

Comment: can't find media.xml file inside xml folder. I am getting problem getting configuration error while uploading file in moviemasher.\